# Nested route in react rendering 404 on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${appPath}`} component={asyncDashboard} />
    <Route path={`${appPath}FundReleases`} component={asyncFundReleases} />
    <Route path={`${appPath}Wizard`} component={asyncWizard} />
</Switch>
```

On the server when I redirect from another app to http://devserver:70/AppName/ , asyncDashboard component renders fine. But when I redirect from another app directly to http://devserver:70/AppName/Wizard, it gives me 404 - File or directory not found. When I load Wizard via history.push, the Wizard component loads fine, but I also want to load wizard directly via http://devserver:70/AppName/Wizard.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `appPath` ends with a `/`?

Comment: I've had similar problems using Netlify and react-router, are you sure your devserver is configured properly to let the app handle routing?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Yes, it ends with /

Comment: @Altareos The appserver is configured to properly.